# Angular 2 useExisting providers

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-services

What are the usages for `useExisting` provider?

Is it `useExistingOrThrowIfThereIsNone` or `useExistingOrCreateIfThereIsNone`? Can one of these behaviours be chosen on purpose somehow, depending on our needs? If one of them is not supported, can an unsupported one be emulated?

The documentation is totally unclear on that and just gives an example that `useExisting` can reuse an instance from `useClass`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With this example

```
providers: [
    A, 
    {provide: B, useClass: A}, 
    {provide: C, useExisting: A}]
```

If you have

```
constructor(private a: A)
```

an instance for the first provider is created.

```
constructor(private b: B)
```

an instance for the 2nd provider is created

```
constructor(private c: C)
```

the instance of the first provider is injected.

If you start fresh with

```
constructor(private c: C)
```

an instance for the first provider is created and injected

Comment: `useExisting` is like an alias for another provider. `useClass` is just a new provider that maps from the requested type to the actual type but the key is the requested type.

Comment: You don't need to do anything to make `Service` a singleton everywhere except, just providing it once at the root component. Angular2's DI maintains a single instance per provider. If you provide it just once there will be only one instance.

Comment: This is currently not supported. Also Angular2-provided stuff like `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` have to be added explicitly at `bootstrap()` or the root component.

Comment: To avoid 2 different instances to be created when 2 different providers point to the same class.

Answer (score 15):

When we write `{provide: A, useClass: B}`, Angular will create map between **token** `A` and **class** `B`.

When we write `{provide: A, useExisting: B}`, Angular will create map between **token** `A` and **token** `B`.

Difference between these maps:

- token A -> instance of class B
- token A -> token B -> instance of some class for token B

Answer (score 15):

Just small addition/clarification to @GünterZöchbauer's answer.

It's actually useExistingOrThrowIfThereIsNone when we're talking about **tokens**. useExisting creates an alias to another **token**, not an **instance**, so there **must** be the token referred by useExisting, otherwise exception will be thrown. But when we're talking about **instances**, it will work as long as last token in the chain registers **instance**, so in that sense it is useExistingOrCreateIfThereIsNone.

Consider this:

```
// T = token, I = instance
providers: [
    {provide: B, useClass: A}, // T[B] => I[A]
    {provide: C, useExisting: A}] // T[C] => ??? - there's no T[A] declared

...
constructor(private a: B) {} // works
...
constructor(private a: C) {} // throws an exception:
```

In this case second declaration will throw an error because **token** C refers to **token** A but there is no **token** A declared anywhere, even though there's an **instance** of class A in the injector. Angular will not attempt to create **instance** A for **token** C or associate **token** C with existing **instance** A. I just accidentally verified it in one of my projects. :)

The following will work though because of reasons well described in other answers:

```
providers: [
    {provide: B, useClass: A}, // T[B] => I[A]
    {provide: C, useExisting: B}] // T[C] => T[B] => I[A]

...

constructor(private a: B) {} // works
...
constructor(private a: C) {} // works
```

In this example **instance** of A will be created for **token** C even if there was no **instance** A created previously for **token** B. So, for **token** C it is "use whatever **instance** should be provided for **token** B", and for **token** B it is "use existing **instance** A or create new if there's none".

Comment: The last line is wrong! for token B it is "create a new instance of A" (no matter if there exists one)

Comment: Nope. Last line is correct. Instances are reusable and being cached by angular by default. If that's not how it works in your case then something else is going on. Post your code in separate question and someone will answer it.