# useValue vs useFactory

Tags: angular

What is the difference between `useValue` and `useFactory` providers?

It seems `useFactory` returns a value and `useClass` also does the same.

Answer (score 28):

- `useFactory` takes a factory function that is expected to return the value and also can have dependencies (require instances of other providers passed as parameter)

See for example the `config:ConfigService` parameter required by the factory function in [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611614#37611614)

- `useValue` is just the value that is injected as is
- `useClass` expects a type name and Angular creates an instance from the passed type and also resolves and passes constructor parameters to the class if there are any
- There is also `useExisting` which is like an alias for an already registered provider. The use case is to provide the same instance of a provider with different keys.

See [Angular 2 useExisting providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420933/angular-2-useexisting-providers/38421655#38421655) for an example.

Answer (score 19):

**`useValue:`** will assign current whatever assigned object instance which you provided.

**`useFactory`:** It also does the same, You can configure a factory object based on other dependency inside `function` and before returning an instance of it.

```
{ 
  provide: CustomDependency,
  useFactory: () => {
    if (IS_A) {
      return new A();
    } else {
      return new B();
    }
  }
}
```

> You can use `useFactory` to configure your dependency
>   at configuration time. Its same as that of `config` phase Angular 1,
>   where you are modifying or forming a dependency as you needed.

Answer (score 6):

My **basic** understanding...

You can think is `useValue` roughly as static assignment; the Provider adheres to the [ValueProvider](https://angular.io/api/core/ValueProvider) interface:

Given that you always want the value `'12345'` when using `@Inject(INJECTION_TOKEN)`, then this will work,

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: INJECTION_TOKEN,
    useValue: '12345',
  },
],
```

This will always return '1234' when using `@Inject(INJECTION_TOKEN)`.

Whereas,

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: INJECTION_TOKEN,
    useValue: () => '12345',
  },
],
```

Will provide a function for `INJECTION_TOKEN` that will return '12345'.

`useFactory` expects a function to produce the injected value. The return value of the factory function is what is injected. This, `useFactory` provider type uses [FactoryProvider interface](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider). An optional array of `deps` can be added that allows for arguments to be passed to the factory function.

Finally, `useClass`,

> Configures the Injector to return an instance of useClass for a token. [1]

The injector will provide an instance of the provided class. Noteworthy, the injector will also provide the injected dependencies of the [`Type<any>`](https://angular.io/api/core/Type), the value type of field, `useClass` on the `ClassProvider` [1] interface.

To summarize, choose `useValue` to provide the same injected value each time*, `useFactory` when the injection value should be computed at runtime, and `useClass` when you want the injector to construct a value of `Type<any>` to provide.

* Note: The value provided to `useValue` can be a function so can produce dynamic values if the injected value is invoked, because it is a function.

[1] [ClassProvider](https://angular.io/api/core/ClassProvider)