# Provide a service in Angular5 = "is not a function"

Tags: angular, angular5, ngx-charts

I want to override a service from an other module, but i got the error "is not a function"

In my component (module 1) i inject the servie

```js
public constructor(private chartProgressService: ChartProgressService) {
}
```

In module 2 i override the servive in providers

```js
providers: [
    {
        provide: Configuration,
        useClass: AppConfiguration,
    },
    {
        provide: ChartProgressService,
        useValue: MyChartProgressService
    },
    {
        provide: LOCALE_ID,
        useValue: 'de-DE',
    }
],
```

and this is MyChartProgressService

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class InnogyChartProgressService {

    public getUnit(): string {
        return '';
    }

    public getValue(currentValue: number, maxValue: number): number {
        return currentValue;
    }
}
```

The call this.chartProgressService.getValue() in my component returns the error

```
HeaderComponent.html:11 ERROR TypeError: this.chartProgressService.getUnit is not a function
at ChartProgressComponent.ngOnInit (chart-progress.component.ts:33)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12369)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13836)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14729)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14670)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HeaderComponent.html:11)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14655)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13802)
at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
```

I think i need your help! Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the problem you use `useValue` with `MyChartProgressService`, how about you change it to `useClass`?

Comment: Oh yes, that was easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one more thing is if you want to use `InnogyChartProgressService`

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class InnogyChartProgressService {
}
```

then it should be like

```js
 {
    provide: ChartProgressService,
    useClass: InnogyChartProgressService 
},
```

in you case you are referring different class called `MyChartProgressService` and change useClass

---

As per angular guide if you want to replace service with new service than you need to extend service , for example given in angular guide

to do this , replace old Logger with new one

```js
[{ provide: Logger, useClass: BetterLogger }]
```

it extends old one in new one as below

```js
@Injectable()
export class EvenBetterLogger extends Logger {
}
```

Read : https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#alternative-class-providers

Answer (score 0):

{
   provide: ChartProgressService,
   **useClass**: MyChartProgressService
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually was the following: If you use `useValue` in your providers definitions, you have to use an actual instance there like `new MyChartProgressService()` or object literal. But if you want to just give a "blueprint" and let it be instantiated automatically by Angular, use `useClass` with a type, so in your case `useClass: MyChartProgressService`.

More explanation can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722393/angular-2-usevalue-vs-usefactory).