# useClass vs useExisting

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-di

When should we use `useExisting` provider instead of `useClass`?

```
providers: [
{provide: Class1, useClass: Class1}, 
{provide: Class2, useExisting: Class2}]
```

---

***REMARK:*** I have not found an exact question on SO. And for better indexing decided to create this specific one here, although I found this answers:

- [Angular 2 useExisting providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420933/angular-2-useexisting-providers)
- [useValue vs useFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722393/angular-2-usevalue-vs-usefactory)
- [Angular 2 useExisting providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420933/angular-2-useexisting-providers)

*but would like to have more real examples*

Comment: This appears to be a real life example https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#aliased-class-providers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Angular creates factory for providers that will be used to instantiate provider.

I usually use the following table to understand the difference between types of providers.

[image]

As we can see in the picture above all of providers can be presented similar  `useFactory`. When it's the time to get an instance of provider angular just calls `factory` function.

So for `useClass` angular resolves dependency from parameters array and then calls constructor with parameters while for `useExisting` angular gets existing resolved instance and returns it.

Use cases:

1) Don't expose full functionallity

```typescript
{ provide: PublicApi, useExisting: PrivateImpl }

{ provide: MinimalLogger, useExisting: LoggerService }

{ provide: PlatformRef, useExisting: PlatformRef_ }

{ provide: ApplicationRef, useExisting: ApplicationRef_}

{ provide: Sanitizer, useExisting: DomSanitizer },

{ provide: Compiler, useExisting: JitCompiler }
```

2) Build tree

```typescript
{ provide: Parent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => TreeViewComponent) }
```

3) Avoid circular dependency

```typescript
{ provide: BaseComponent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyComponent) }
```

4) Provide common tokens

```typescript
{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ForbiddenValidatorDirective, multi: true }

{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => EmailValidator),  multi: true }

{ provide: NgControl, useExisting: forwardRef(() => NgModel) }

{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormGroupDirective) }

{ provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, multi: true, useExisting: MyDatePickerComponent }
```

If we replace
`useExisting` with `useClass`, then we’d be registering a new class instance

Comment: For multi providers construct, what if I forgot to put `multi: true` in some of the provider entries?

Comment: @GlennMohammad If you forgot to put  multi: true then it  will overrides the previously registered directives.

Comment: @DeepakPatidar Actually, as of Angular 6, it will throw an error now: "Provider parse errors: Mixing multi and non multi provider is not possible for token InjectionToken_..." So that's pretty neat! :)

Answer (score 41):

**useExisting** - create refrence to service [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-use-existing?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) 

 **useClass** - create new instance of service [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-useclass?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 30):

Normally you get an instance per provider.

```ts
{provide: Class1, useClass: Class1},
```

is equivalent with just

```ts
Class1
```

With

```ts
{provide: Class1, useClass: Class3},
```

you can configure, that when a constructor requests `Class1` Angular DI creates an instance of `Class3` and passes it to the constructor.

```ts
{provide: Class2, useExisting: Class2}
```

doesn't result in an instance being created, but you can see this rather than an alias.
If a constructor requests `Class2`, Angular DI looks for another provider for key `Class2` and injects the instance from this `Class2` provider.
You can see `useExisting` like a reference to another provider or an alias.

Comment: Gunter, I don't get the explanation they've given here https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms for using `useExisting` rather than `useClass`. Can you please simplify this?

Comment: @karthikaruna seems reasonable to me. I don't know what the problem is. A `useExisting` is just a redirect to another provider.

Comment: The terms `Injectable` and `Provider` are synonymous and any class with a `decorator` is injectable. `useExisting: ForbiddenValidatorDirective` means use the provider `ForbiddenValidatorDirective` when asked for the provider with the key `NG_VALIDATORS`. Is this understanding from that context correct?

Comment: `Injectable` and `Provider` are 2 different things. The injectable is a class DI can create an instance of, or a provided value that might be passed to a constructor. A provider is an entry in a registry of providers that DI maintains and that allows to lookup up providers by key (key is the type of a constructor parameter, a string or an `InjectToken`). The provider also holds information about how to "create" the injectable value/instance. DI looks up a provider, the provider provides the value, and DI passes the value (instance of an injectable or a value provided as-is) to a constructor.

Comment: If you register `MyClass` as provider, this is the short form of `{ provide: MyClass, useClass: MyValue }` where `provide: MyClass` is the key a provider can be found with, and `useClass: MyValue` is a strategy passed to the provider that informs the provider what value it should provide for this key. `useClass: MyValue` means "use `new MyClass(...)`" and `useExisting: Foo` means, that DI needs to be consulted to lookup a provider for `Foo` and then inject the value this provider provides.

Comment: Clean so far! One thing, in that context, I don't see that they have provided `ForbiddenValidatorDirective` by any of the ways you've stated above. How does the DI looks up `ForbiddenValidatorDirective` when asked for `NG_VALIDATORS` as `ForbiddenValidatorDirective` is not in the providers registry?

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. `ForbiddenValidatorDirective` is provided implicitly, like every component can inject it's parent component. I don't know the exact details in this case and don't have time to investigate. But it should give you an idea how this can work.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my naive questions man! You're great!

Comment: Just one more naive question if you don't mind :). Where exactly in that context, is the provider `NG_VALIDATORS` asked for?

Comment: Form controls inject applied validators to call them https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=NG_VALIDATORS&type=

Comment: How can we differentiate between the useclasses? like when you have `{provide: Class1, useClass: Class3}, ` and we still in some cases need `Class1` instead of `Class3`, how do we choose?

Comment: There is no way to choose. One thing you can do is to decide where you put such a provider. If you add it to a lazy loaded module it overrides this for this module and other modules loaded by this module directly or transitively. If you add it do a component it overrides it for this component and all childs/descendants. Check the docs for more details.